# Remove time stamp from personalization strings

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, string

I looking for a way to remove the time stamp of a date field when using personalization strings. 
I got this format when using PS: 3/1/2020 12:00:00 AM. I want to remove that part "12:00:00 AM". 
Here is my personalization strings for the date field: `%%=lookup('CONTRATS_HABITATION','DATE_EFFET_CONTRAT','CONTACT_ACCOUNT_ID',CONTACT_ACCOUNT_ID)=%%`

I have read in another post that I could use that function `FormatDate(Now(), "MMM dd, yyyy")` by replacing the Now() by my date field. But I don't know how to proceed. 
Does anyone have some insights about this?

Thanks!

***UPDATE*** I just wanted to add a solution to my last comment. Since the field is contained in a non-sendable data extension, I had to find a way to retrieve it and to truncate the date field. Here is my solution: %%=v(FormatDate(lookup('CONTRATS_HABITATION','DATE_EFFET_CONTRAT','CONTACT_ACCOUNT_ID',CONTACT_ACCOUNT_ID), "dd MMMM yyyy",,"fr-CA"))=%%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, you can use the FormatDate function to truncate the time part from your datetime.

In your case, it would be something like:

```
Set @DATE_EFFET_CONTRAT_TRUNC = FormatDate(DATE_EFFET_CONTRAT, "MMM dd, yyyy")
```

**The output would be:**

> Mar 01, 2020

In this case, I assume your personalization string is `DATE_EFFET_CONTRAT`

Also, I see that you are using french language. So just in case you need to format your date using the french format, you can try something like:

```
Set @DATE_EFFET_CONTRAT_TRUNC = FormatDate(DATE_EFFET_CONTRAT, "dd MMMM yyyy",,"fr-CA")
```

**The output would be:**

> 01 mars 2020

If you want to use only this date in your subject line, you can try:

```
%%=v(FormatDate(DATE_EFFET_CONTRAT, "dd MMMM yyyy",,"fr-CA"))=%%
```

Otherwise, you need to use create a @subjectLine variable, and concatenate all your content to it on the email content and put in your subjectline textfield: `%%=v(@subjectLine)=%%`

**Reference:**

Checkout this [FormatDate](https://ampscript.guide/formatdate/) page for more options..

Comment: Hi @Rachid Mamai, thanks for the very quick reply. 
Should I just copy paste that code in my subject line for example?

Comment: It depends on your use case..

Comment: In the subject line I just want to show the value for "DATE_EFFET_CONTRAT" according to subscribers' data

Comment: @GrégoireSarrola I've updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rachid Mamai! 
The data doesn't show up because my field is contained in another data extension (linked via data relationship and in data designer). I will dig into that issue.

Comment: I just wanted to add a solution to my previous comment. 
Since the field in contained in a non-sendable data extension, I had to find a way to retrieve it and to truncate the date field. Here is my solution:  %%=v(FormatDate(lookup('CONTRATS_HABITATION','DATE_EFFET_CONTRAT','CONTACT_ACCOUNT_ID',CONTACT_ACCOUNT_ID), "dd MMMM yyyy",,"fr-CA"))=%%